# how to put images without overlapping the background image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, background-image

I'm creating a template for a website. Up to now I have created a full-screen background image. I want to include images at the bottom of the background, but images are overlapping. So how to solve this problem by using HTML or css?

[image]

Comment: You need to show us your code:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has `<footer>`. So if you want to put images at the bottom, use them inside the footer tag.

To address overlapping problem, include each image inside a different `<div>` tag and maintain proper structure. You can use `<div class="container">` for each image.
Ex- First div tag is for contain every image at whole and seperate div tags are for each image.

```
<div class="container-fluid>
<div class="container"> <img src="img1.jpg"></div>
<div class="container"><img src="img1.jpg"></div></div>
```

Hope this is the answer you're looking for